# best way to set up a MySQL database for storing web data

Tags: php, mysql

I will be using curl to retrieve thousands of adult websites.  My goal is to store them in MySQL to allow users to easily search the new database and find their desired page without having to endure all the popups, spyware, etc.

It will be an adult website search engine... kinda the google of adult websites, but without the malware sites that find their way onto google from time to time.

At first run I downloaded about 700K lines at about 20 GB of data.  Initially I stored all info in a single table with columns for URL, HTML PAGE CODE, PAGE WITH NO HTML TAGS, KEY WORDS, TITLE and a couple more.

I use a MATCH AGAINST query to search for the users desired page within TITLE, KEY WORDS, PAGE WITH NO HTML in any variety of combinations or singularly.

My question is... would I be better off to break all these columns into separate tables and would this improve the speed of the searches enough that it would matter?

Is there any advantage to storing all the data in multiple tables and then using JOIN's to pull the data out?

I am just wondering if I need to be proactive and thinking about high user search loads.

Comment: _You stay classy, San D-_ I mean, SO.

Comment: While you're being proactive, you might want to hire a lawyer and/or a bodyguard. The adult industry isn't likely to be all that happy with your blatant copyright infringement. Also, expect your cURL bot to be blocked pretty quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL isn't good with full-text search and never was.

Look into [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/about/sphinx/) or [Lucene/Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), they're the best fit for the job. I'd suggest sticking to the former.

Comment: Nice, will these integrate ok with PHP?